# run 5 thread in parallel

Tags: java, multithreading

https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B4cxDnPAjctLfmwxSlZhcFhDZEd4aF9QQnBaZWpQT1VhSnN4UE4xdG9NcDc1Nm55YzZzdW8&usp=sharing
code in this link above
the main method run 5 threads
when  I run the code every thread share variables with other thread 
and output should in this structure
E:\TIPZIL8\1\osama\2\osama12.pdf
E:\TIPZIL8\2\ali\3\Ahmed23.htm
E:\TIPZIL8\3\ali\4\amr34.htm
E:\TIPZIL8\4\ali\5\hossam45.htm
E:\TIPZIL8\5\ali\6\ali56.htm

but the out put different

```
  public class GetPDFLink implements Runnable {
private String id;
private String link;
private String info;
private String name;

public GetPDFLink(String id,String link,String info,String name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.link = link;
    this.info = info;
    this.name = name;
}
public void run() {
    Download a = new Download();
    try {
        System.out.println(name + " is running");
        System.out.println(id+"&&&&&&&&&&&");
        a.downloadHTMLWithPDFolder(id, link, info, name);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(GetPDFLink.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null,           ex);
    }
    try {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(GetPDFLink.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    System.out.println("after sleeping");
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    GetPDFLink m_1 = new GetPDFLink("1","http://ir.pdf.com/secfiling.cfm?filingID=1437749-15-7272","pdf1","osama");
    GetPDFLink m_2 = new GetPDFLink("2","http://ir.pdf.com/secfiling.cfm?filingID=1437749-15-3861","pdf2","Ahmed");
    GetPDFLink m_3 = new GetPDFLink("3","http://ir.pdf.com/secfiling.cfm?filingID=1437749-15-3698","pdf3","amr");
    GetPDFLink m_4 = new GetPDFLink("4","http://ir.pdf.com/secfiling.cfm?filingID=1437749-15-3369","pdf4","hossam");
    GetPDFLink m_5 = new GetPDFLink("5","http://ir.pdf.com/secfiling.cfm?filingID=1437749-15-3369","pdf5","ali");
    Thread t1 = new Thread(m_1);
    Thread t2 = new Thread(m_2);
    Thread t3 = new Thread(m_3);
    Thread t4 = new Thread(m_4);
    Thread t5 = new Thread(m_5);
    t1.start();
    t2.start();
    t3.start();
    t4.start();
    t5.start();
    System.out.println("this might print first!");

}
```

}

```
    public class Download{        
    static String company_id = "";
    static String company_Name = "";
    static String pdfInfo = "";
    static String pdfLinkDownload = "";
    static String s= "";
        public void downloadHTMLWithPDFolder(String company_id,String pdfLinkDownload,String pdfInfo,
        String company_Name)
        throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
            int company = 0;
    Download.company_id = company_id;
    Download.company_Name = company_Name;
    Download.pdfInfo = pdfInfo;
    Download.pdfLinkDownload = pdfLinkDownload;
    BufferedInputStream in = null;
    FileOutputStream fout = null;
    File file=new File("E:\\ALL");

    company = Integer.parseInt(company_id);
    company ++;

    s =  ""+company;

    if(!file.exists())
    {
        file.mkdirs();
    }

    File fileid=new File("E:\\ALL\\"+company_id);

    if(!fileid.exists())
    {
        fileid.mkdirs();
    }   

    File file1=new File("E:\\ALL\\"+company_id+"\\"+company_Name);

    if(!file1.exists())
    {
        file1.mkdirs(); 
    }

    File filec=new File("E:\\ALL\\"+company_id+"\\"+company_Name+"\\"+s);

    if(!filec.exists())
    {
        filec.mkdirs(); 
    }      

    try {
        System.out.println("open...");
        pdfInfo.replaceAll("/","");
        fout  =new FileOutputStream("E:\\ALL\\"+company_id+"\\"+company_Name+"\\"+s+"\\"+company_Name+company_id+company+".htm");
        System.out.println("LINK : " + pdfLinkDownload);
        in = new BufferedInputStream(new URL(pdfLinkDownload).openStream());


        final byte data[] = new byte[1024];
        int count;
        while ((count = in.read(data, 0, 1024)) != -1) {
            fout.write(data, 0, count);
        }
    } 
    finally
    {
        if (in != null)
        {
            in.close();
        }
        if (fout != null) {
            fout.close();
        }
        System.out.println("fileDwonloaded   ....***");
    }
}
```

}

**Edit** :: The Problem Solved by remove static variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fields in `Download` class are `static`. Remove the `static` modifier for each field. You should also update the usage of these fields in the class.

The class would look like this:

```
public class Download {
    String company_id = "";
    String company_Name = "";
    String pdfInfo = "";
    String pdfLinkDownload = "";
    String s= "";

    public void downloadHTMLWithPDFolder(String company_id,
        String pdfLinkDownload,
        String pdfInfo,
        String company_Name)
        throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
            int company = 0;
        this.company_id = company_id;
        this.company_Name = company_Name;
        this.pdfInfo = pdfInfo;
        this.pdfLinkDownload = pdfLinkDownload;
        BufferedInputStream in = null;
        FileOutputStream fout = null;
        File file=new File("E:\\ALL");

        company = Integer.parseInt(company_id);
        company ++;
        s =  ""+company;

        if(!file.exists()) {
            file.mkdirs();
        }

        File fileid=new File("E:\\ALL\\"+company_id);
        if(!fileid.exists()) {
            fileid.mkdirs();
        }
        File file1=new File("E:\\ALL\\"+company_id+"\\"+company_Name);
        if(!file1.exists()) {
            file1.mkdirs();
        }
        File filec=new File("E:\\ALL\\"+company_id+"\\"+company_Name+"\\"+s);
        if(!filec.exists()) {
            filec.mkdirs();
        }
        try {
            System.out.println("open...");
            pdfInfo.replaceAll("/","");
            fout  =new FileOutputStream("E:\\ALL\\"+company_id+"\\"+company_Name+"\\"+s+"\\"+company_Name+company_id+company+".htm");
            System.out.println("LINK : " + pdfLinkDownload);
            in = new BufferedInputStream(new URL(pdfLinkDownload).openStream());


            final byte data[] = new byte[1024];
            int count;
            while ((count = in.read(data, 0, 1024)) != -1) {
                fout.write(data, 0, count);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (in != null)
            {
                in.close();
            }
            if (fout != null) {
                fout.close();
            }
            System.out.println("fileDwonloaded   ....***");
        }
    }
}
```